# Using CURL POST with Json format payload

Tags: curl, payload

I am testing a API using CURL in my local server. I need to use CURL GET request with a Json parameters.

My Json will be like:
{ "key1" :[{subkey1":"subvalue1","subkey2":"subvalue2"}],
"key2" :[{subkey3":"subvalue3","subkey4":"subvalue4"}]}
And I tried:
curl -i http://localhost/test/api?key1

or save my json file as a test.txt and use
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '@D:/test.txt' http://localhost/test/api?key1

.....but none of them work....
So how could I use a curl to create a post request with payload?
Thanks!

I want to get the return value as
key1 = [ ***]
key2 = [####]

Comment: At first you said you were trying to make a GET request and then later a POST request - which once does the server actually accept?

Comment: oh, sorry, it should be a post request...not GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to send JSON with curl. Consult your API documentation to check which method you should use.

Here are some common ones:

sending json in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request can be done like:

```
curl http://example.com --data-urlencode json='{"foo":"bar"}'
```

the request will then look like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

json=%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D
```

json in a `multipart/form-data` POST request can be done like:

```
curl http://example.com --form json='{"foo":"bar"}'
```

the request will then look like

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 152
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------ca36a58e4d11c82e

--------------------------ca36a58e4d11c82e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"foo":"bar"}
--------------------------ca36a58e4d11c82e--
```

sending raw json in a POST request can be done like:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST --data-binary '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

the request will then look like

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 13

{"foo":"bar"}
```